# Installing SSL certificates on Tomcat in AWS Linux Infrastructure

Tags: tomcat, amazon-ec2, configuration, ssl-certificate

could use a little help. I’m a junior sys admin, I was thrusted into a devops / sys admin role in a 100 person business when our devops guy quit with a weeks notice. Our internal company.org sites are down because our go daddy ssl certs expired. I’m frantically trying to restore everything and having a bit of trouble understanding the process everything is requiring here. We have an AWS infrastructure, couple DNS servers, tomcat, apache servers, etc. What I do know is that these renewed cert files from go daddy need to be imported into tomcat, then tomcat needs to be restarted. Servers are AWS linux. I think how this all goes down is I take the 3 .crt files from godaddy, cat them into a .pem file, then using openssl export that and our private key to a p12(I’m sure it’s p12), then using keytool import that into tomcat. Then restart tomcat. This is where I’m at.

```
openssl pkcs12 -export -in company.pem -inkey /usr/local/bin/backups/privatekey.pem  -out company.p12

No certificate matches private key
```

where company.pem is all the godaddy certs merged using cat. I found the private key using find.

Researching is giving me some conflicting information, so I must not be understanding something thats assumed I know. I *think* maybe I must have to somehow export the private key into the .pem file by first decrypting it? I’m not even sure that’s the road I should take. Maybe I’m way off. Any sort of insight would be greatly appreciated. Thank you all.

Comment: GoDaddy has a page for Tomcat SSL - [Here](https://ca.godaddy.com/help/tomcat-generate-csrs-and-install-certificates-5239)

Comment: Stack Overflow is a site for programming and development questions. This question appears to be off-topic because it is not about programming or development. See [What topics can I ask about here](http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic) in the Help Center. Perhaps [Super User](http://superuser.com/) or [Unix & Linux Stack Exchange](http://unix.stackexchange.com/) would be a better place to ask. Also see [Where do I post questions about Dev Ops?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/134306)

Comment: Take a breath. :) Then answer these questions: 1) Where is the private key used to generate your Certificate Request (CSR)? 2) Which servers are terminating TLS? AWS ELB? Apache httpd? Apache Tomcat?

Answer (score 0):

I assume that your `privatekey.pem` somehow doesn't match the certificates within the `company.pem`.

My personal script (taken from the *Let's Enrypt forum*) for importing my SSL certificates from [Let's Encrypt](https://letsencrypt.org) into a keystore for tomcat is the following:

```
openssl pkcs12 -export -in fullchain.pem -inkey privatekey.pem -out fullchain_and_key.p12 -name tomcat
keytool -importkeystore -deststorepass <password> -destkeypass <password> -destkeystore keystore.jks -srckeystore fullchain_and_key.p12 -srcstoretype PKCS12 -srcstorepass <password> -alias tomcat
```

So I assume you need the right files and then your script will do the job.